# What is an adjective for "weaker than weak"?

Tags: terminology, article-writing

I defined a notion (say, some kind of equivalence) in three forms, the first implies the second, which in turn implies the third.

I would like to use "strong", (nothing), and "weak" to describe them.  But some one of great importance already used "weak" for something strongly related to the second form.  To be compatible with previous studies, I have to refer to the first as "strong", to the second as "weak".

The third is weaker than the weak.  I need an adjective to describe it.  "Weaker" is not good enough.  The notion also induce an adjective (e.g. equivalent) and a verb (e.g. equal), so I also need an adverb. "Weakerly" sounds strange.

Is there a standard adjective to describe the third notion? I now use "feeble".

I also see the possibility of defining a "stronger than strong" form.  Suggestions are also welcome for this.

Comment: Why not change the name of the middle one to "moderate" and use "weak" for the weakest?  Otherwise you could simply qualify it to "super weak" or something like that.

Comment: weaker ... (is that what you want?)

Comment: @GregoryGrant backward compatibility ...

Comment: "extra weak" then ,or "weakest"

Comment: @GEdgar when I need an adverb, "weakerly" feels weird.

Comment: superweak, ultraweak

Comment: There are plenty of words which mean what you want, such as flaccid, limp, floppy. But I don't know how good they'd look in a mathematical treatise. Maybe your choice of feeble is the best.

Comment: It would be epic to migrate this to [English SE](http://english.stackexchange.com) :-)

Comment: uberweak sounds good

Comment: are you sure you *need* to use the term weak? be a bit more creative! for example in probability one gets convergence almost surely => in probability => in law (also known as weak). 
You can take inspiration as how and why this new type of convergence was defined in the first place. Say you need it to show that a certain property, called "friendly" holds. Call this new type of convergence friendly convergence, or something like that! just an idea :)

Comment: or if you want to go for the win you could also call it "Chen convergence" :-P

Comment: "Totally weak." -- Eric Cartman.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't think there is a *standard* adjective to describe this. If there is, we would need to know the context of the terms *stronger* and *weaker* to answer. It sounds like you are defining this *weaker-er* notion in your paper (since you have to introduce a new term), so it is really on you to give it a name. Now to compile a list of suggestions:

- subweak
- weakerer
- superweak
- ultraweak
- extraweak
- weak' (*weak prime*)
- weak*
- weak$^2$ (*weak squared*, or *weak two*, or *too weak*)
- feeble
- anemic
- fragile
- puny

Comment: I like the tension between "subweak" and "superweak." Which is weaker? :P

Comment: More seriously: "ultraweak" is already used, in [mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraweak_topology) and [biology/physics](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/101113449380076L).

Comment: @user28111 Depending on the context where OP is using it, it might be useful to use *ultraweak* if the relationship similar to the weak-topology and ultraweak-topology relationship (the lack of context we are given makes it hard to tell).

Comment: @Noah: *Feeble* is also used: a topological space is *feebly compact* if every locally finite open cover is finite.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, I can imagine that whoever first used *feebly compact* had this same problem: "*what do I call something that is weaker than weak?*"

Comment: Note that weak* includes "" (the empty weak).  Might I suggest weak+ instead (or even more strictly, weak-weak+)? =P

Comment: If the "weaker" one is a weakened version of the "weak" one, perhaps just go "weak weak", as in "the weak weak form", because it's the weak form of the weak form.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I suggest to use "double weak" and "triple weak". See [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2885601/157643)

Answer (score 12):

I can't resist adding this one to the list: what do you call a principle weaker than Weak Konig's Lemma?

[Funny you should ask . . .](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.2281v1.pdf) (Weak Weak Konig's Lemma)

Ayup, we're a creative bunch. :P

---

Oh my goodness: [page 18, after proposition 9.1](http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Andre_Nies/publication/261065681_Logic_Blog_2011/links/0a85e53697cae59940000000.pdf). It's merely suggested, but: "Weak Weak Weak Konig's Lemma."

---

And heaven forbid we be at a loss to describe [something not as weak as weak](https://math.dartmouth.edu/~frg/aimRandQsLive.pdf)! (Page 8, definition 4.5.) "Strong weak truth table reducibility"

Comment: got me thinking weak$^2$

Comment: Can you please bring the linked content into your post? Thanks

Comment: And in your first link, we find then that (Theorem 1.7) the ***DNR is striktly weaker than the WWKL***. Where does this all lead us to...

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Well, that's different: DNR isn't a principal of the form "Every [property] binary tree has a path," so - although there's an obvious connection - it's not really of the type of this question.

Comment: @Noah - ok, thanks for that information. I tended now to withdraw that comment, but maybe someone else might have the same idea - so better I leave it here?

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Sure.

Answer (score 6):

I would say "pathetic" or "puny".

Answer (score 2):

In PDE theory, the term "very weak solution" is in wide use. [Google results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22very%20weak%20solution%22).

Answer (score 2):

Very weak, according to xkcd:

[image]

But, more seriously, you can also put it the other way.

For example, in case of the Riemann Hypothesis, the Riemann Hypothesis is implied by the Generalized Riemann Hypothesis, which is in turn implied by the Grand Riemann Hypothesis.

But that maybe overkill.

Comment: Link: https://xkcd.com/1310/

Comment: https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/1310:_Goldbach_Conjectures

Answer (score 1):

An interesting challenge!
A couple of additional ones I didn't see in previous answers:

strong > weak > light (adverb 'lightly')

strong > weak > delicate (adverb 'delicately')

strong > weak > wimpy (adverb 'wimpily') - sounds less formal but has precedents in technical areas.

strong > weak > tentative (adverb 'tentatively') - likely less useful, has overtones of non-strength attributes (eg: hesitation).

Answer (score 1):

How about **double weak** and **triple weak**?

Advantages:

- Clearer in rank than normal [intensifiers](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/adjectives-intensifiers-strong-adjectives) (*sub, very, super, extra, ultra*). A *triple weak* is clearly weaker than a *double weak*, while it is not clear whether a *super weak* is weaker than a *very weak* or not. If we have a stronger version of a weak proposition, but weaker than the normal one, then we can just renumber the ranks and all are good.
- More natural in language than *weak²* or *weak**, and less redundant than *weak weak*
- Reduce cognitive load for the naming, and leave more energy to actually studying it

Comment: To me comes into mind:"the mother of weakness" or so. Then more creative might be the addition of qualitative terms like "that proposition is lousy weak" or "absurdely weak" ... (not really serious, though...)

Comment: I just suggest using "double" or "triple" as a way to avoid confusions made from "very" or "super", as the question asks. Anyway, your proposition is hilariously strong.